# Simultaneous parameter pack expansion error for unused template type definition

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, variadic-templates

The problem that I have encountered is the following warning from clang (c++14):

> Pack expansion contains parameter pack 'v_seconds' that has a different length (3 vs. 1) from outer parameter packs

The issue is encountered in the following example code:

```
template<typename... v_firsts>
struct types_list {
    template<typename... v_seconds>
    using pairs_list = types_list<std::pair<v_firsts, v_seconds>...>;
};

using my_types_list = types_list<short, int, long>;

using my_pairs_list = my_types_list::pairs_list<short, int, long>; // GOOD

template<typename... v_pack>
using any_pairs_list = my_types_list::pairs_list<v_pack...>; // BAD
```

How I interpret the error is that somehow a specialization of `any_pairs_list` in which `v_seconds` has a length of 1 is encountered, and then naturally an error is encountered.

However the code above is the *entire* example code - I *never* use a specialization of `any_pairs_list`.

So, I have to conclude that a specialization is nevertheless created...

Now, the usual TMP forking question:

```
if (This an intentional behavior of the variadic syntax) {
    Can someone reference some documentation so that I can learn more?
} else if (This a known clang decision or problem) {
    Can someone reference some discussion?
} else {
    Can someone please name the issue / mistake?
}
```

P.S. I have tested using apple's installation of Clang (v8.1.0) and also with Visual Studio 2017 Clang extension. Unfortunately I don't have a linux environment to test in...

Comment: If the above is your "entire code", then you're missing `#include <utility>`, or otherwise `std::pair` is nowhere defined.

Comment: It [works with GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zHLMEpcTTKd1l0SJ).

Comment: The error is a bit unclear... I wonder if it is `v_firsts` or `v_seconds` that the compiler thinks has a length of 3...

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you for checking the code with GCC - seems like the issue might be with clang.

Comment: Btw., you probably wanna add typename and template keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that Clang uses some type of heuristic to check for inherently uninstantiable templates. Perhaps it (spuriously) decides that there is one argument to the alias in `any_pairs_list` because it doesn't deal with pack expansions properly, and then substitutes some unique synthesized type to test whether that could work in principle. After all, you do get the exact same error message if you don't use a pack but just one bog-standard template parameter.

Reported as [#32905](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=32905).

Comment: I think I have seen variations of this questions around elsewhere. I think what happens is that when `types_list<short, int, long>::pairs_list` is named, then `types_list<short, int long>` is implicitly instantiated. This will instantiate the member template `pairs_list`, and will try to expand `v_firsts` and `v_seconds` right at that point (since `alias-declarations` are not delay-instantiated, because they are not definitions, when their enclosing class template is instantiated).

Comment: Then it runs afoul of "All of the parameter packs expanded by a pack expansion shall have the same number of arguments specified.". But `v_seconds` has no argument yet. So I think this snippet is ill-formed. For this to be valid, you can use a class template with a typedef in it, instead of an alias template, as shown in the example here: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#6  With that, the member template has a definition-body and the pack expansion will not be immediately instantiated.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb This sounds pretty sketchy. Can you back up your first comment's claim with the standard?

Comment: [temp.inst]p1 and p2, [basic.def]p2, [temp.mem]p1 and [temp.variadic]p6

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Sure, but Clang does not issue the diagnostic when we write `types_list<short, int, long>::pairs_list` in the "good" case.

Comment: I think that's the actual error. Probably a consequence of it being "NDR": The member template declaration is ill-formed, but it is not yet instantiated, so no diagnostic is required. Any progrogram that is ill-formed; NDR has the equivalent of undefined behavior in it (the Standard requires nothing for such a program from an implementation). However, I think Clang/LLVM folks have higher ambitions than relying on such licenses, so it's still not good that clang allows that line of code, IMO.

Comment: the declaration of the member of the class template (`types_list<typename ...>`) is instantiated (to an alias template declaration member of `types_list<short, int, long>`). But not the declaration of the member of the class template specialization (`types_list<short, int, long>`).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "This will instantiate the member template pairs_list, and will try to expand v_firsts and v_seconds right at that point" I really don't see why that would happen. We simply don't have v_seconds, how could we expand anything?

Comment: I have to admit, I have no idea. Initially I thought that it clearly should instantiate it, and then result in an error. But, since there are no arguments for `v_seconds` yet, I'm unsure. Maybe it's worth asking for a clarification about this.

Comment: Thank you Columbo for reporting, and also Johannes Schaub for the discussion. The discussion & cited documentation is just what I was hoping for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround.  Make `pairs_list` a struct with a member typedef named, for example, `type`.  Since this works I would say that this is a bug in the `using` alias template in Clang.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename... v_firsts>
struct types_list {
    template<typename... v_seconds>
    struct pairs_list {
      typedef types_list<std::pair<v_firsts, v_seconds>...> type;
    };
};

using my_types_list = types_list<short, int, long>;

using my_pairs_list = my_types_list::pairs_list<short, int, long>::type;

template<typename... v_pack>
using any_pairs_list = typename my_types_list::pairs_list<v_pack...>::type;

// Let's see what has been deduced

template < typename T >
void show_signature() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main() {
  show_signature<my_types_list>(); // T = types_list<short, int, long>

  show_signature<my_pairs_list>(); // T = types_list<std::pair<short, short>, std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<long, long> >

  show_signature<any_pairs_list<int,long,double>>(); // T = types_list<std::pair<short, int>, std::pair<int, long>, std::pair<long, double> >
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henri for the work-around suggestion & the verification that without an alias this expansion works.